# Reading a ListView SelectedItems collection from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm trying to perform some actions on the selected items in a ListView on a Windows Forms application from a background thread. I've got a delegate method in my code like so:

```
private delegate ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection dlgGetSelectedJobs();

private ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection GetSelectedJobs()
{
    if(listViewJobViewer.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var dlg = new dlgGetSelectedJobs(GetSelectedJobs);
        return listViewJobViewer.Invoke(dlg) as ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection;
    }
    return listViewJobViewer.SelectedItems;
}
```

This is being called elsewhere on a background thread using the following:

```
                    foreach(ListViewItem job in GetSelectedJobs())
                    { 
                        // Do stuff
                    }
```

However whenever the code enters the foreach loop I get a cross-thread exception and I'm not sure why... Any assistance gratefully received!

Comment: when and where is this loop called/executed? In the constructor of the form?

Comment: @MongZhu - I've just tried changing that line in the GetSelectedJobs() method and Visual Studio is showing an error saying: ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection JobSubmission.GetSelectedJobs() has the wrong return type

Comment: The loop is being executed when the user clicks a button to remove the selected jobs from the list. The code is in the event handler for the button_Click event.

Comment: ok then try this please: `return listViewJobViewer.Invoke(new Action(()=>GetSelectedJobs());` But actually it seems for me that the removal of items is the problem and not the getting of the `SelectedListViewItemCollection`. Can you post the code where you remove the items?

Comment: @MongZhu I tried the new line you suggest and Visual Studio still isn't happy: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). The selected items aren't actually removed from the collection, they're removed from the back-end database and the items in the ListView are cleared and then refreshed. The method doing this is OK as its the same one used to populate the ListView in the first instance and that works OK.

Comment: it should compile if you include the `as ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection;` but I really don't think that this is the problem here. " The method doing this is OK" is it running on a different thread then the UI ?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes the method that populates the ListView in the first instance also runs on a background thread. I've managed to work around it by doing something different, so I'll post my answer below, thank you for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to MongZhu for the assists!

I've managed to work around this issue by altering my delegate method to use Linq to return a List based on the selected items in the ListView:

```
private delegate List<ListViewItem> dlgGetSelectedJobs();

private List<ListViewItem> GetSelectedJobs()
{
    if(listViewJobViewer.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var dlg = new dlgGetSelectedJobs(GetSelectedJobs);
        return listViewJobViewer.Invoke(dlg) as List<ListViewItem>;
    }
    return (from ListViewItem i in listViewJobViewer.SelectedItems select i).ToList();
}
```

I'm still not sure why it wouldn't work when I was trying to return the collection, but this seems to work correctly.